# how to map values of single array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array e.g.

```
array (
  city => Newyork,
  amount => 1000
);
```

How can I get the output as follow?

```
Newyork => 1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nothing special, basic php:

```
$a=array( 'city' => 'Newyork',
'amount' => '1000'
);

echo $a['city'] .  ' => ' . $a['amount'];
```